# Cannot pass URL from JavaScript to PHP in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm trying to get three values from a front-end form in JavaScript and then passing those values to the Laravel controller.

I can get two values (Key and Id) but I cannot get the third value because it is a URL. If I comment the URL variable then I'm getting the rest of the two values (Key and Id) but if I'm passing the URL along other two values then I'm not getting anything in my controller.

I have tried these two JavaScript methods encodeURIComponent() and encodeURI() to encode the https URL given but still no luck.

This is my code in JavaScript:

```
let get_url = $("#get-url").val();
let get_key = $("#get-key").val();
let get_id = $("#get-area").data('getId');
toastr.remove();
if (get_key) {
    var req = new Image();
    req.src = api_url + 'senddata/' + get_id + '/' + get_key + '/' + get_url;
    console.log(req.src);
       toastr.success(MEASURE.UTILITIES.translate("success_request_successfully_sent"));
        $("#btn-send-data-request").hide();
        $("#block_get_url").hide();
        $("#block_get_key").hide();
        $("#csv_get_request_message").show();
    } else {
        toastr.error(MEASURE.UTILITIES.translate("error_enter_valid_data"));
    }
```

Comment: can you also share the html?

Comment: I don't have HTML, because I just want to pass these three values to the controller in Laravel.

Comment: in that case can you also show the output of console.log(req.src);

Comment: Here is the console.log(req.src);

    http://app_api.dev/senddata/371/654987654316549871246/https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=DPMOWqjQDIPkaOultvAH

Comment: Hi, your schema is most likely screwing up your laravel router. 1st  option - try removing "https://" from your url variable (this may not help as it will leave other / and they may mess with router, not sure 100% ho laravel's router is different from zend's). 2nd option - pass in the url variable via GET parameter:  ?url="https://..." this will separate your url var from the main route.

Answer (score 0):

Your get_url contains a url, which i believe has https:// or http://

This is a problem when you are adding to the API URL you are constructing as adding more / changes the ROUTE.

For example your API URL expects `req.src = api_url + 'senddata/' + get_id + '/' + get_key + '/' + get_url;`
 which is something like `http://www.laravel.com/api/senddata/123/123/urlhere`  but you are making is something like `http://www.laravel.com/api/senddata/123/123/http://urlhere` which means you are altering the ROUTE.

To solve that you can URL Encode the URL before passing it.

Change your code to this should work : `let get_url = encodeURIComponent($("#get-url").val());`

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp

Comment: Yes, I have already mentioned that, so how am I supposed to pass the URL to the controller?

Comment: Simos, I have already tried URL Encode as I have mentioned it in my question and it didn't help anyway.

Comment: @Mohsin Intazar You can try to replace / characters with | for example and then replace back from laravel. Can you try this as a test to see if it works ?

Comment: I'm trying to do this 
        let azure_url = $("#azure-url").val();
        let my_url = azure_url.replace("/", "|");

But this is only replacing the first "/" only, here is the output from console.log.

http://app_api.dev/senddata/371/https:|/www.google.com/?gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=DPMOWqjQDIPkaOultvAH